# Vertx Websockets starts encoding-decoding in loop after connecting second client

Tags: java, websocket, netty, nio, vert.x

I have simple Vertx-based websocket chatting app. It consists of two parts MsgServerVerticle and MsgClientVerticle (source code below). So, if I am instantiating one server and only one client it looks like working normally. After second client connects, server starts trying to announce it to other clients. And things gonna weird. Log says that netty backed are encoding-decoding websocket frames continuously in loop. There is no difference what type of frames I am using, binary or text, issues are the same.
[log screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/akUYj.jpg)

What's wrong?

MsgClientVerticle Source code:

```
private Logger L;

private String eBusTag;
private String backwardTag;
private String targetHost;
private int port;
private String id;
private String path;

private EventBus eBus;

private HttpClient client;

public MsgClientVerticle(String eBusTag, String targetHost, int port, String path, String id, String backwardTag) {
    this.eBusTag = eBusTag;
    this.targetHost = targetHost;
    this.path = path;
    this.port = port;
    this.id = id;
    this.backwardTag = backwardTag;

    L = LoggerFactory.getLogger(eBusTag);
}

@Override
public void start(Future<Void> startFuture) throws Exception {
    L.info("Initializing client connection to " + targetHost + ":" + port + path);
    eBus = vertx.eventBus();

    try {


        client = vertx.createHttpClient();

        client.websocket(port, targetHost, path, webSock -> {
            L.info("Connected to " + targetHost + ":" + port + "/" + path);
            eBus.publish(backwardTag, Utils.msg("Connected"));
            webSock.binaryMessageHandler(buf -> {
                eBus.publish(backwardTag, Utils.bufToJson(buf));
            });
            eBus.consumer(eBusTag).handler(msg -> {
                JsonObject message = (JsonObject) msg.body();
                webSock.writeBinaryMessage(Utils.jsonToBuf(message));
            });
        });
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        L.error("Null Pointer: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    startFuture.complete();
}

@Override
public void stop(Future<Void> stopFuture) throws Exception {
    L.info("Connection to " + targetHost + ":" + port + "/" + path + " closed");
    client.close();
    stopFuture.complete();
}
```

And MsgServerVerticle source:

```
private Logger L;

private String path;
private int port;
private String eBusTag;
private String backwardTag;

private HttpServer server;

private EventBus eBus;

private Set<ServerWebSocket> conns;

public MsgServerVerticle(int port, String eBusTag, String backwardTag) {
    this.port = port;
    this.eBusTag = eBusTag;
    this.backwardTag = backwardTag;

    conns = new ConcurrentSet<>();
    path = eBusTag;

    L = LoggerFactory.getLogger(eBusTag);

}

@Override
public void start(Future<Void> startFuture) throws Exception {
    eBus = vertx.eventBus();
    L.info("Initializing server instance at port " + port);

    server = vertx.createHttpServer();

    server.websocketHandler(webSock -> {

        if (!webSock.path().equals(path)) {

            webSock.reject();

        } else {

            conns.add(webSock);

            conns.forEach(sock -> {
                if (sock != webSock) {
                    sock.writeBinaryMessage(Utils.jsonToBuf(Utils.msg("SERVER: new client " + webSock.remoteAddress().toString())));
                }
            });

            eBus.publish(backwardTag, Utils.msg("SERVER: new client " + webSock.remoteAddress().toString()));

            webSock.binaryMessageHandler(buf -> {
                JsonObject msg = Utils.bufToJson(buf);
                conns.forEach(sock -> {
                    if (sock != webSock) {
                        sock.writeBinaryMessage(buf);
                    }
                });
                eBus.publish(backwardTag, msg);
            });

        }

    });

    server.listen(port);

    startFuture.complete();
}

@Override
public void stop(Future<Void> stopFuture) throws Exception {
    conns.forEach(sock -> {
        sock.writeFinalTextFrame("Server is shutting down...");
    });
    server.close();
    stopFuture.complete();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to reproduce your original problem. But I had to make a few changes in the first place to test it.

One change is in initialization of your server:

`this.path = "/" + eBusTag;`

Otherwise this check will always fail:

`if (!webSock.path().equals(this.path)) {`

Since `websock.path()` will always start with `/`, hence `/anything`=/=`anything`

Second, please take a look how I initialized the clients, and check if you do the same:

```
    final Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx();

    vertx.deployVerticle(new MsgServerVerticle(8080,
            "ebus",
            "back"), new DeploymentOptions().setWorker(true), (r) -> {
        vertx.deployVerticle(new MsgClientVerticle("ebus",
                "127.0.0.1",
                8080,
                "/ebus",
                "a",
                "back"), new DeploymentOptions().setWorker(true), (r2) -> {
            vertx.deployVerticle(new MsgClientVerticle("ebus",
                    "127.0.0.1",
                    8080,
                    "/ebus",
                    "b",
                    "back"), new DeploymentOptions().setWorker(true), (r3) -> {
                System.out.println("Done");
            });
        });
    });
```

And third, as far as I could understand, your Utils class is something you implemented. My implementation looks as follows:

```
public class Utils {
    public static Buffer jsonToBuf(final JsonObject message) {
        return message.toBuffer();
    }

    public static JsonObject bufToJson(final Buffer buf) {
        return buf.toJsonObject();
    }

    public static JsonObject msg(final String msg) {
        return new JsonObject("{\"value\":\"" + msg + "\"}");
    }
}
```

Hope that helps pinpoint your problem.